# PHP Get URL Parameter and its Value

Tags: php, arrays, url, parameters, foreach

How do I split the URL and then get its value and store the value on each text input?

URL:

```
other.php?add_client_verify&f_name=test&l_name=testing&dob_day=03&dob_month=01&dob_year=2009&gender=0&house_no=&street_address=&city=&county=&postcode=&email=&telp=234&mobile=2342&newsletter=1&deposit=1
```

PHP:

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$para = explode("&", $url); 
foreach($para as $key => $value){   
    echo '<input type="text" value="" name="">';    
}
```

above code will return:

```
l_name=testing  
dob_day=3  
doby_month=01  
....
```

and i tried another method:

```
$url = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$para = explode("&", $url); 
foreach($para as $key => $value){   
    $p = explode("&", $value);
    foreach($p as $key => $val) {
       echo '<input type="text" value="" name="">';
    }   
}
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php

Comment: Use $_GET. If you're breaking down a query string from another location, use parse_str(). No need to explode and loop everything.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not using $_GET global variable?

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value)
{  
  // do your thing.
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$queryArray = array();
parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'],$queryArray);

var_dump($queryArray);
```

Comment: Just for me ... why would you `use parse_str()` over `$_GET` ? i can understand the nerd to use it if the string you want to parse if not the url used to call the executing php ...

Comment: How would $_GET handle ?arr[]=foo+bar&arr[]=baz

Comment: `$_GET['arr'];` <- would be an array

Comment: In that case, it's just me being nerdy

Answer (score 4):

php has a predefined variable that is an associative array of the query string ... so you can use `$_GET['<name>']` to return a value, [link to `$_GET[]` docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

You really need to have a look at the [Code Injection page on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection) you need to ensure that any values sent to a PHP script are carefully checked for malicious code, PHP provides methods to assist in preventing this problem, [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/htmlspecialchars)

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `$_GET` array.

If your query string looks like this:
`?foo=bar&fuz=baz`

Then you can access the values like this:

```
echo $_GET['foo']; // "bar"
echo $_GET['fuz']; // "baz"
```